# Netbeans 8.2 wont apply themes

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

For some reason, Netbeans IDE 8.2 won't apply any different themes than the original one.  Has anyone else had an issue with this?  I have applied the new theme and restarted the application many times without success. Thank you.

[image: Netbeans 8.2 Theme Issue]

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to identify what is wrong since everything in your screenshot looks perfect, and **Sublime-Theme** works for me using NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10. See the file with the tab NewServlet.java in the screen shot below.

Note that using **Sublime-Theme** does not impact everything. For example, the *Projects* and *Navigator* panels don't change. Since your screen shot only showed the *Options* window, and the *Start Page* doesn't change in the editor either, are you absolutely certain that none of your files in the editor are using **Sublime-Theme**?

[image: sublime-theme]

Also, you say that "*Netbeans IDE 8.2 won't apply any different themes than the original one*", but NetBeans comes bundled with several themes, such as **NetBeans** and **NetBeans 5.5** as shown in the screen shot below. How many options are shown in the profile drop list for you? If you select a different theme from the **Profile** list and click **Apply** the rendering of your files in the editor should change immediately. Is that happening?

[image: nbNorwayToday]

If so, the problem is probably confined to the installation of **Sublime-Theme**. Try deleting **Sublime-Theme** (the button is in the top right corner of your screen shot), and then import the zip file again to see if that fixes the problem. Also, verify that the **Sublime-Theme** zip file you downloaded can be manually unzipped since it might be a corrupt file.

Another thing to try is using some alternative plugins. Select **Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins** and then install **Dark Look and Feel Themes** and **Darcula LAF for NetBeans**. If those don't work either then there is something fundamentally wrong with the installation of NetBeans.

Finally, this article titled [The complete guide to tuning the appearance of NetBeans](https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/the-complete-guide-to-tuning-the-appearance-of-netbeans) may be helpful.